# Memory Corruption Detected - Occurs when debugging through JUnit

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, junit, jvm

I am getting the following logs when trying to run my JUnit tests in debug mode. Any help on unblocking this issue so that i can proceed with debugging my code through my tests, would be much appreciated:

19:48:35.933 0x11f3bc00 omrport.359    *   ** ASSERTION FAILED ** at ../../omr/port/common/omrmemtag.c:145: ((memoryCorruptionDetected))
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "traceassert", detail "" at 2021/04/11 20:48:35 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/Users/stackoverflow/IdeaProjects/candidate/core.20210411.204835.12566.0001.dmp' in response to an event
JVMDUMP012E Error in System dump: The core file created by child process with pid = 12567 was not found. Expected to find core file with name "/cores/core.12567"
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/Users/stackoverflow/IdeaProjects/candidate/javacore.20210411.204835.12566.0002.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /Users/stackoverflow/IdeaProjects/candidate/javacore.20210411.204835.12566.0002.txt
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/Users/stackoverflow/IdeaProjects/candidate/Snap.20210411.204835.12566.0003.trc' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to /Users/stackoverflow/IdeaProjects/candidate/Snap.20210411.204835.12566.0003.trc
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "traceassert", detail "".

Comment: Any chance you're using libraries like PowerMock? Usually, regular JUnit doesn't produce errors like this... Probably the best would be if you could add a test (or at least its structure) that causes this error to the question

Comment: @Mark Bramnik No, I don't have a PowerMock dependency in place. This error is occurring even when I put a completely blank JUnit test in place with just a print statement in it and try to debug it. What I am finding confusing, is that i can run the tests perfectly fine if i run them out straight; the issue is only occurring when i try to run them in debug mode.

Comment: I just figured out my problem: the debug mode's runtime configuration in my Intellij IDE was defaulting to an unexpected java version on my local machine.